# Parameters not getting passed from Angular to API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

What am I missing here?

My Take and Skip variables contain values, however when I check on the API side the parameters are null.

My API

```
[HttpGet(Order = 0)]  
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(uint? Take, uint? Skip)
    {
     // DO stuff
    }
```

Angular Call to API:

```
getData(    
    skip: number = null,
    take: number = null
  ): Observable<MyData[]> {
    console.log("skip=" + skip);
    console.log("take=" + take);
    return this.http
      .get(this.API_URL + "", {
        params: new HttpParams()
          .set('Skip', (skip == null) ? null : skip.toString())
          .set('Take', (take == null) ? null : take.toLocaleString())

      })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return <MyData[]>response.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show what the final URL is that is being sent from the browser? Use the debugging tools and network tab.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing old Http and new HttpClient

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace references to old, deprecated `HttpModule` with `HttpClientModule`, then replace `Http` with `HttpClient` and modify your code to remove the map operator (not needed with the new http client)

```
return this.http
  .get<MyData[]>(this.API_URL + "", {
    params: new HttpParams()
      .set('Skip', (skip == null) ? null : skip.toString())
      .set('Take', (take == null) ? null : take.toLocaleString())
})
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question and it seems to be incomplete(unfinished ternary operator).

Comment: @peinarydevelopment FYI that's a bit hard to edit from a phone, hence the code block that disappeared. I was in the middle of correcting it when you downvoted. And mixing both modules can cause issues.

Comment: Could be, but it looks like JDS is using asp.net as the back end and is calling it wrong. that is probably the main issue, but it is hard to correct without more code

Comment: What additional code can I pass on?  Yes I am using ASP.NET for the API (Core 2.0).

Comment: When I try the above code I get the error:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
TS) Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'HttpClient' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: That appears to work, I'm now getting a CORS error. (Even though I set it on the server side to take all requests (While developing))

Comment: @peinarydevelopment care to review your statement/downvote?

Comment: @JDS you should open another question with  the new error and server config details